# How to install/configure Eclipse for Java ME development for the Nokia Series 40? (Windows)

Tags: eclipse, java-me, installation, nokia, series-40

What is required to start developing for Nokia Series 40 with Java?

Answer (score 0):

All that's needed to develop for Nokia with Java ME is:

- [Java Development Kit (6)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) - required to develop Java applications
- [Eclipse Java (Helios)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/heliosr) - need this to code, compile, debug and others
- [Nokia Series 40 SDK (v.6)](http://www.forum.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/cc48f9a1-f5cf-447b-bdba-c4d41b3d05ce/Series_40_Platform_SDKs.html) (login required) - used to emulate the Nokia platform
- [Mobile Tools for Java](http://www.eclipse.org/dsdp/mtj/) - Eclipse extension for mobile development (integrates with the Nokia SDK)

I think the order of the items is the right order.